# Javascript - Dynamically convert js including array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a json like this:

```
var getBody = req.body;

console.log(getBody);

{"tags":[{"tag":"Peter"},{"tag":"Maria"}],"term":"Jack","type":"name"}
```

I want to dynamically convert it to sth like:

```
[ '%Peter%', '%Peter%', '%Maria%', '%Maria%', '%Jack%', 'name' ]
```

... so I need each tag value twice if available.

Currently I have this script:

```
var input = req;
var sqlVal = Object
    .entries(input.body)
    .reduce(function(result, entry) {
        const key = entry[0]
        const value = entry[1]
    if( key === 'term' ) {
    result.push('%' + value + '%')
    } else if( key === 'tags' ) {
        if ( value.length > 1 ) {
            for ( let i=0; i < value.length; i++ ){
                result.push('%' + value[i] + '%')
            }
        } else {
            result.push('%' + value + '%')
        }
    } else if( key === 'type' ) {
        if ( value.includes(",")  ) {
            var array = value.split(",");
            for ( let i=0; i < array.length; i++ ){
                result.push(array[i])
            }
        } else {
            result.push(value)
        }
    }
    return result
    }, [])
```

... but I'm getting:

```
console.log(sqlVal);

[ '%[object Object]%', '%[object Object]%', '%Jack%', 'name' ]
```

How can I get the desired result?

Desired result:

```
[ '%Peter%', '%Peter%', '%Maria%', '%Maria%', '%Jack%', 'name' ]
```

...I use this script in a node.js mysql query

Edit:

The SQL I need it for looks in the above case like this:

```
SELECT name, abc from table WHERE (name LIKE ? OR abc LIKE ?) AND (name LIKE ? OR abc LIKE ?) AND (name LIKE ? OR abc LIKE ?) ORDER BY name;
```

Note: (name LIKE ? OR abc LIKE ?) is also dynamically built.

Comment: why peter and maria are repeated twice?

Comment: ... because :-) ... its the way how the sql is set up. So I need it twice in this case

Comment: I don't see those duplicates in your sample data `getBody`.

Comment: will the json always have that format?

Comment: ... yes ... there are not there ... but I need to duplicate it in the desired result

Comment: ... the number of tag values vary (unlimited) ... or tags doesn't even exist at all

Comment: What is the logic that determines how the output comes from the input? Why the duplicates?

Comment: I gotta say I'm confused as to why you guy are so concerned about the duplicates. It's not the problem OP asked for help with, so...

Comment: I added the SQL I need it for ... please see above

Comment: 'tag' can be a name or an id ... so I'm search in two different fields for the same input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Object.values(req.body)
  .flatMap(x => {
    switch (Object.prototype.toString.call(x)) {
      case '[object String]': return `%${x}%`;
      case '[object Array]': return x.map(y => `%${y.tag}%`);
    }
  });
```

Should give desired output. Note that `Array.prototype.flatMap` is pretty new, you may need to polyfill.

Answer (score 1):

You can `reduce` the tags array again and push the results to the original accumulator:

```js
var data = {"tags":[{"tag":"Peter"},{"tag":"Maria"}],"term":"Jack","type":"name"};

var result = Object.entries(data).reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
  if (k === 'tags') {
    a.push(...v.reduce((acc, {tag}) => {
                  acc.push(`%${tag}%`, `%${tag}%`);
                  return acc;
                }, []));
  } else {
    a.push(k === 'type' ? v : `%${v}%`);
  }
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be simply corrected, when you iterate through the array, you get an object with key tag, so you need to push `value[i]["tag"]` to get the actual value.

```
var input = JSON.parse('{"tags":[{"tag":"Peter"},{"tag":"Maria"}],"term":"Jack","type":"name"}');//req;
console.log(input);
var sqlVal = Object
    .entries(input)
    .reduce(function(result, entry) {
        console.log(result,entry);
        const key = entry[0]
        const value = entry[1]
        console.log(key,value);
    if( key === 'term' ) {
    result.push('%' + value + '%')
    } else if( key === 'tags' ) {
        if ( value.length > 1 ) {
            for ( let i=0; i < value.length; i++ ){
                console.log("value is",value);
                result.push('%' + value[i]["tag"]  + '%');//here you are getting object, you should draw the tag value of that object here
            }
        } else {
            result.push('%' + value + '%')
        }
    } else if( key === 'type' ) {
        if ( value.includes(",")  ) {
            var array = value.split(",");
            for ( let i=0; i < array.length; i++ ){
                result.push(array[i])
            }
        } else {
            result.push(value)
        }
    }
    return result
    }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the property "tags", your code is:

```
if( key === 'tags' ) {
    if ( value.length > 1 ) {
        for ( let i=0; i < value.length; i++ ){
            result.push('%' + value[i] + '%')
        }
    } else {
        result.push('%' + value + '%')
    }
```

But `value` in this case is an array of *objects* (in the example), not of strings. So `value[i]` is something like `{ tag: "Peter" }`. When you concatenate that with `%` the object is coerced into a string, which is "[object Object]". Instead, you'll want to retrieve the value *inside* the tag object:

```
            result.push('%' + value[i].tag + '%')
   //                                 ^^^^
```